# How to measure an Avro message size in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I have some producer that produces Avro records into a Kafka topic. How do I know how big (in bytes) each message is?

Comment: I wanted to know what size in bytes some messages being sent where and I dug into the Java code to find out.

The quickest and easiest way for me was to put a break point on the following line in the KafkaProducer class:

    `int serializedSize = AbstractRecords.estimateSizeInBytesUpperBound(apiVersions.maxUsableProduceMagic(),
                        compressionType, serializedKey, serializedValue, headers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to clarify what do you mean by message size. Currently message size is considered the size of a Record Batch, which includes batch metadata plus individual records: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#recordbatch

Before sending data to Kafka, the producer batches data depenging on `batch.size` and `linger.ms`. Once data is batched, records are compressed depending on `compression.type` config. This means, you won't know the exact record batch size til your batch is ready to be sent.

If you are only interested in the bytes of the record value size, you can check the bytes array size after message is [serialized](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serializer.html#serialize-java.lang.String-T-).

To know the amount of bytes received by a topic, you can measure this metric on the server side: `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=BytesInPerSec` or checking `outgoing-byte-rate` metric on the producer side.

Comment: I used confluent control center to find the topic size (one replica) and divide that by the offset change, would that give me the message size in byte array?

Comment: If retention or compaction is configured the size of the topic and number of offsets could not be accurate (e.g. start offsets != 0). Also consider message size variation between messages. If you measure number of records per second and number of bytes per second, you could divide those to get a rough avg record size.